# HDF5 string serialization details in pandas?

Tags: pandas, saddle

I am the author of Saddle (saddle.github.io), which provides functionality similar in spirit to pandas (but in Scala on the JVM). I'm trying to ensure that the HDF5 serialization format of pandas' DataFrame is interoperable with that of Saddle. I'm currently implementing string array serialization in Saddle. So my question is how the pandas DataFrame serializes strings. If I create an HDF5 file in pandas as follows:

```
from pandas import *
h = HDFStore('tmp.h5')
f = DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1: ["a", "b", "c"], 2: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]})
h.put("f1", f)
h.close()
```

And h5dump the resulting tmp.h5 file, I see that the string block (block2_values) is stored as datatype H5T_VLEN and attribute

```
 ATTRIBUTE "CLASS" {
    DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
          STRSIZE 8;
          STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
          CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
          CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
       }
    DATASPACE  SCALAR
    DATA {
    (0): "VLARRAY"
    }
 }
```

This hints at an ASCII character set; however, the bytes I see encoded do not seem to correspond to ASCII (ie, "a", "b", "c"). Also, I'm curious where STRSIZE 8 comes from. Can anyone shed light on the implementation details of string serialization which occurs via pandas -> pytables -> hdf5? (I'd also be happy with any pointers to code in pandas/pytables where I can start digging deeper myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You picked an example that on the surface seems very simple, but is actually fairly complicated behind the scenes. This ends up storing 3 different blocks of data (1 for each dtype), and each of these stores and index and the data.

The object which you stored is what I call a `Storer` format, meaning the numpy arrays are written all at once, so once written they are not changeable. See docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables

PyTables docs are here: http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/declarative_classes.html#the-atom-class-and-its-descendants

These strings unfortunately are stored as a python pickle in this particular format of storage, so I don't know if you can decode them cross-platform.

You will have an easier time reading a `Table` object, which is stored using more basic types, that are easily exported (there is a section in the docs on exporting to R for example).

try reading this format:

```
In [2]: df = DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1: ["a", "b", "c"], 2: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]})

In [4]: h = pd.HDFStore('tmp.h5')

In [6]: h.put('df',df, table=True)

In [7]: h.close()
```

using the PyTables `ptdump -avd tmp.h5` utility, this yields the following. If you are reading < PyTables 3.0.0 (which just came out), or in py3 (which we are going to support in 0.11.1). Then strings are all utf-8 encoded written as bytes. Prior to (PyTables 3.0.0,), strings are written as ascii I believe.

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.0',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/df (Group) ''
  /df._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 12 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := [],
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := b'nan',
    non_index_axes := b"(lp1\n(I1\n(lp2\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\np3\n(cnumpy\ndtype\np4\n(S'i8'\nI0\nI1\ntRp5\n(I3\nS'<'\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntbS'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp6\nag3\n(g5\nS'\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp7\nag3\n(g5\nS'\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp8\natp9\na.",
    pandas_type := b'frame_table',
    pandas_version := b'0.10.1',
    table_type := b'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'values_block_1', 'values_block_2']]
/df/table (Table(3,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "values_block_2": StringCol(itemsize=1, shape=(1,), dflt=b'', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2621,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 19 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'values_block_1',
    FIELD_3_FILL := b'',
    FIELD_3_NAME := 'values_block_2',
    NROWS := 3,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.6',
    index_kind := b'integer',
    values_block_0_dtype := b'float64',
    values_block_0_kind := b"(lp1\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\np2\n(cnumpy\ndtype\np3\n(S'i8'\nI0\nI1\ntRp4\n(I3\nS'<'\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntbS'\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp5\na.",
    values_block_1_dtype := b'int64',
    values_block_1_kind := b"(lp1\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\np2\n(cnumpy\ndtype\np3\n(S'i8'\nI0\nI1\ntRp4\n(I3\nS'<'\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntbS'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp5\na.",
    values_block_2_dtype := b'string8',
    values_block_2_kind := b"(lp1\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\np2\n(cnumpy\ndtype\np3\n(S'i8'\nI0\nI1\ntRp4\n(I3\nS'<'\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntbS'\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\ntRp5\na."]
  Data dump:
[0] (0, [1.5], [1], [b'a'])
[1] (1, [2.5], [2], [b'b'])
[2] (2, [3.5], [3], [b'c'])
```

Probably best to contact me off-line to discuss further.

Comment: "These string unfortunately are stored as a python pickle in this particular format..." will this stay like this or are there plans to use msgpack here. I am asking because I have seen the msgpack branch that you are working on.

Comment: msgpack is an independent serialization format having nothing to do with PyTables. The pickle I am refering to is an in-line way that PyTables saves variable length strings.

Comment: I thought that it was pandas specific and didn't know this is pytables behaviour. If pytables used msgpack it would be easier for other languages to read the data but obviously their target is python.

Comment: For the most part PyTables IS completely cross-platform, this particular case though is not, as it uses variable length strings; my table example above IS cross-platform as it uses fixed-length strings.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for the example. However, the table format is much slower to read/write than the "pandas" format. I guess as usual there is no simple solution with all the benefits.

Comment: storer format has its uses but since u cannot append data it is unsuitable for really large data sets. in addition u cannot query. you pay a small penalty for writing a table. what are u trying to accomplish?

Comment: we are writing rather huge (up to 18m rows) blocks to disk that will then be read from several processes many times in the following days (write once, read many, no subqueries). there is now a use case where we want to share this data (also) to a scala program and it would have been a convenient way to share without too much time loss with writing/reading (the msgpack branch shows me that it is not easy to accomplish good performance with msgpack/avro etc). io speed is critical, especially for fast iteration.

Comment: ``Table`` is an excellent format for this, with read times very comparable to ``Storer``. However, more important is the ability create the data in a straightforward manner, but possibily writing in several append operations (so you do not have to keep all of the data in memory at once), m2c

Comment: We could explore storing arrays of strings in a single packed UTF8 buffer. It's a bit of work but I have some code lying around that might help.